# How to identify 2 duplicate consecutive cells in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

How can I identify duplicate consecutive cells, not in adjacent columns but adjacent rows like my sample below:

```
4/30/2016
5/12/2016
4/5/2016
5/10/2016
5/10/2016
4/30/2016
5/12/2016
5/10/2016
```

In this example, the 4th and 5th rows contain 5/10/2016, which is the only pair matching the requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Put a conditional formatting on all cells with the formula comparing the current cell to the cell above, for example, in the cell C2, put `=C2=B2`.

Then set an obvious format (red background), and they will stick out.

You can even filter by color to get them all at once.

Comment: Thank you!  I changed it as =C2=C3 since I am comparing cells in the same column.  It works.  Thank you!!